# Pass page1 input value to page2 variable

Tags: php

I am passing value entered in **input text box** [page1.php]  to **post variable** present in page2.php file to get **$output** value , but $output value is not coming in Response.

what wrong i done ?

**page1.php**

```
<input type="text" value="awb" name="awb" id="awb"  />

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#awb").on('keyup', function () {

    var awb =  $("#awb").val(); 

    $.ajax({
      url: 'page2.php',
      type: 'POST',

      dataType: 'html',
      data: { awb: awb }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      $('#r').append(data);
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php

$post_data['awb']= $_POST['awb']; 


$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sitename.com/page3.php");
// some curl code
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo $output;
```

**page3.php**

```
    <?php

    $trackId = $post_data['awb'];
$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load($trackId, 'track_number');
if ($track) {
    $orderId = $track->getShipment()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
} else {
    //tracking does not exist
}

echo $orderId;

    ?>
```

Comment: You want `data: { awb: awb }` in your `$.ajax()` call, not `"awb": awb`. Voting to close as a _typo_

Comment: @Phil Thanks for comment, i updated your code, but still not getting response.....

Comment: Please update your question to match your actual code

Comment: Some issues, I don't see you adding your payload/data to your curl call on page2.php, on page3.php you need access any data posted through the $_POST superglobal.

Comment: @vickeycolors what is `page3.php` output?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch it will fetch the required `order number` based on `awb`.....

Comment: Is page3.php on a separate domain/host?  Or rather, Is the curl call even required?

Comment: @Progrock i updated page3.php code, right now its in same domain, but it should work if it is in separate domain/host also......

Comment: @vickeycolors are you passing `$post_data` to the curl for `page3.php`?

Comment: @vickeycolors To remind you again, no post data sent to page3.php via cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$post_data['awb'] is a local variable in page 2 which won't be available in page3.

On page 3 use below

```
$trackId = $_POST['awb'];
```

Comment: Thanks  , seems  answer is working, please give me some time to check.....

Comment: Seems odd this is working since there's nothing in OP's code sending the `awb` POST parameter to `page3.php`

Comment: @Phil He isn't sure because it `seems`

Comment: @Phil I guess the payload is somewhere in: `// some curl code`, posting the full code could have helped here.